# AWS S3 sharing access to static website - 403 access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've configured my bucket policy (for a static website hosted on an S3 bucket) so that another account can perform actions on this bucket. The policy looks something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Example permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::00000000000:user/username"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.com"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/username"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The first object in "Statement" specifies that this bucket should be readable by the public, so that anyone can access the site (I am using Route 53 as well).

The second account is able to upload files to the bucket, however once he uploads a file, then access is restricted to that file, i.e. if he uploads index.html to the top-level directory of the bucket, then navigating to the website will produce a 403 access denied error.

I have looked into IAM roles, which I think may be related but would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: At the very least, the uploader from the other account should include the bucket-owner-full-control ACL otherwise he is the sole object owner and you cannot assert any control over the objects. See if that helps.

Comment: What would be the simplest way for him to add that ACL?

Comment: Depends how he is uploading to S3. If using the awscli, add --acl bucket-owner-full-control. If using the JavaScript SDK putObject method, add ACL: "bucket-owner-full-control" to params.